# I am trying to download images using SRTM download, but then this error pops up after the download has been completed

Tags: qgis, python, error, srtm

```
2021-05-26T13:28:44     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Paul Maritz/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SRTM-Downloader\download.py", line 100, in reply_finished
  f = open(self.filename, 'wb')
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Paul Maritz/Documents/Stelmi/QGIS/S26E028.SRTMGL1.hgt.zip'
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Paul Maritz/Documents/Stelmi/QGIS/S26E028.SRTMGL1.hgt.zip` -> you have not the permission to put the zip file in this folder